# Find a non-zero vector $u$ with terminal point $Q(3,0,-5)$ such that $u$ is opposite directed to $v=(4,-2,-1)$.

Tags: vectors

So for this question, this is how i approach

Let's treat initial point as $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and we got the terminal point, so vector of $u$ is $(3-a)$ $(0-b)$ and $(-5-c)$.

I am kind of stuck here as I as if the question was same direction, we just need to find the scalar multiple but opposite direction, how do we approach?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that they mean that the vector we're looking for has to have the same magnitude as the one from the origin to $\langle 4,-2,-1\rangle$ even though the problem doesn't specify that.  Otherwise, there are many possible solutions to this problem.

So, the vector we are looking for is in the direction
$\vec u =\langle-4,2,1\rangle$, which is the opposite direction of the vector $\langle4,-2,-1\rangle$.  That's our slope.  And the magnitude must equal $\sqrt 21$

Starting from the original point $(a,b,c)$ and terminating at $(3,0,-5)$,
we're looking for where

- $3 - a = -4$
- $0 - b =  2$ and
- $-5 - c = 1$

solving these equations, we come up with an original point $(7,-2,-6)$.

Here's a graph that shows that these two vectors have the same magnitude and opposite direction:  http://www.bodurov.com/VectorVisualizer/?vectors=0/0/0/4/-2/-1v7/-2/-6/3/0/-5

Answer (score 0):

More simply, we are looking for $P$ such that

$$u=Q-P =-v $$
therefore

$$P=Q+v =(4,-2-1)+(3,0,-5) =(7-2,-6)$$